# What does the golf ball rollback mean for professional and recreational golfers?

Tags: equipment, golf

The USGA and R&A has mandated by 2028 (for professionals; 2030 for everybody) that golf balls travel no more than 317 yards when hit with a clubhead speed of 125 mph.

This is after bifurcation (providing two different sets of equipment for professional and recreational players) was rejected by golf manufacturers since their marketing campaigns focus on recreational golfers playing the same equipment professionals do.

Ergo, why is this a big deal? This limits excessive distance (which has caused real estate problems in that golf courses no longer had the room to expand to support gains in distance without purchasing surrounding property) while solving the problem that was brought up during discussion of bifurcation.

Comment: You seem to be answering the question *in* the question itself. What exactly is it that you want to know?

Comment: What does the golf ball rollback mean for competitive and recreational golfers? And why is it a big deal? I point out several issues and how this mandate aims to address those issues but that doesn't answer what it ultimately means to competitive golfers (and recreational golfers since the golf ball will be rolled back for them too).

Comment: A simplistic answer is "golfers won't hit the ball as far" but what are the trickling effects of that? Golfers training like long drivers? A black market for golf balls that are conforming now but non-conforming by this mandate? That's predicting the future, but as a consumer, I can't see how I'm affected. Maybe I lose distance but negligibly relative to my abilities. I'm more focused on the competitive aspect of this mandate and how that trickles down recreationally.